# SSH Negotiation Failing To some sites

Tags: ssh

I use SSH extensively to administer a number of systems. Everything was working perfectly until a short while ago when I discovered I could not SSH into some servers (but others work perfectly).

I did recently upgrade to the latest Ubuntu 14.04, and wonder if thats the cause, but more to the point - how can I fix the issue.

In each case I'm sshing across a VPN using public/private keys.  In each case if I manually telnet to port 22 I get the SSH banner.  There is very little to help track down what the problem is, but when I ssh with "-v" the systems I'm trying to access fail after outputing

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
```

When SSH succeeds on the other network I get the following

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA d9:a7:23:9e:93:da:fe:15:54:5c:a3:01:54:b7:0c:be
debug1: Host '114.23.35.78' is known and matches the RSA host key.
```

I can confirm that it appears to be *all* the hosts behind the 1 network which are failing - and there is a fair number of them spanning different versions of CentOS.  (Where I can SSH in the network is using CentOS and Ubuntu based boxes - I can reach both).  All the connections behind the other network appear to work.

In both cases I am trying to use SSH protocol 2 (if I try and force protocol 1 I get "Protocol major versions differ: 1 vs 2)

I've tried clamping MTU on the OUTPUT, but that does not seem to have made a difference.

In

Any ideas how (without local access to the server) I can work out whats going on ?

**EDITS WITH MORE INFO:**

- When I try and SSH from my cellphone (going through the same router and similar VPN), access works fine.
- When I try to SSH from my computer via the cellphone via the Cellular Data connection
  it works fine.
- Regardless of whether I connect my computer to the router via a cable or access point
  it does not allow me to connect.   (I can't connect my computer via my cellphone
  to my AP, but that would be because I can't use the AP as an AP Client and AP at the
  same time)
- There is a rather large number of entries in my routers ARP cache (over 1000) due, 
  I suspect, to P2P activity earlier in the day.  The modem is using "PPP extensions", so
  of-course the MAC address of the IP's is all the same, being that of the modem.  I 
  do not have the option of terminating the PPP session on the router with this modem.
  (Also not sure how relevant this is - I would assume its not relevant as the traffic
  is tunneled using OpenVPN, bypassing the router in a traceroute and also I get a Telnet
  banner.
- Problem does not seem to be IPTABLES related as I dropped iptables on the router of the
  network causing problems.   I can connect to the external interface of the router no
  problems (no VPN), but as soon as I try the internal interface I get the
  problems described.
- Upgrading SSH and OpenVPN did not make any difference, neither did allowing password
  authentication.

Comment: I've found a workaround - by specifying MACs=hmac-md5 in /etc/ssh/ssh_config or passing it as a parameter with -o lets me in, however I really want to know WHY this has suddenly become a requirement - and why it is only a requirement across the VPN.

Comment: Can you provide more output from ssh (the complete session)?  Also enabling more verbose logging on the servers would help as well.  Stepping up to -vv will show more detail.

Comment: You are using a tunnel, so it's probably an MTU problem. Lower the MTU on the tunnel interface (on both sides if you have both under control) and retry.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I already tried fixing the MTU as per my post.  Anyway, the problem disappeared.